# foreach for mybatis returns Null results

Tags: java, foreach, mybatis

My mapper xml is like this.

```
<mapper namespace="EmployeeDaoMapper">
<resultMap id="employeeResultMap" type="Employee">
    <result property="employeeName" column="name"/>
    <result property="employeeId" column="employee_id"/>
</resultMap>


<select id="getEmployees" parameterType="list" resultMap="employeeResultMap">
<!--<select id="getEmployees" resultType="Employee">-->
    SELECT
    <foreach item="item" index="index" collection="list" separator="," >
        #{item}
    </foreach>
    FROM employees
    WHERE LOWER (name) LIKE LOWER(#{searchQuery} +'%') OR
    LOWER(login) LIKE LOWER(#{searchQuery} +'%') OR
    LOWER( employee_id ) LIKE LOWER(#{searchQuery} + '%')
    LIMIT #{resultsLimit}

</select>
```

EmployeeMapper Interface

```
List<Employee> getEmployees(@Param("searchQuery") String searchQuery, @Param("resultsLimit") int
        resultsLimit, @Param("list") List<String> attributes);
```

query returns list of null.

Instead of foreach, if i directly add column names then it works fine.

I am not sure what mistake i am making. I checked query, it is building query correctly, still unable to fetch results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing #{item} to ${item}.  With #{item} you are telling MyBatis that there should be a prepared statement parameter marker and that is invalid for a salect column list.  If you use ${item}, then MyBatis will write the string directly into the SQL.

Comment: Worth to mention that this is a feature from newer version of myBatis. +1 though.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Jeff Butler.

I would add change `parameterType="list"` to `parameterType="map"` as named parameters are provided through a Map

Comment: yeah, but Nihar declared his 'List<String> attributes' and is referring to that method-parameter explicitly because of his '@Param("list")'. It would've been clearer of he'd named it '@Param("attributes")'